# How to calculate turtles within a certain distance in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to calculate the number of shops within a certain distance of the turtle location. I tried both methods that I write below and I get the same radius. I want to increase the radius to include more than the neighbour patches but changing the value in-radius from 3 to 500 doesn't make a difference in the model. Is there a different way to calculate the shops, let's say within 5 patches from where the turtle is located?

```py
turtles-own [   healthy-exposure
              unhealthy-exposure ]
                
to setup
   ca
   ask households [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                    set   size   0.9
                    set   shape "person"
                    set   color  grey ]
   ask healthy-shops [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                       set   shape "house"
                       set   size   0.6
                       set   color 52 ]
   ask unhealthy-shops [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
                         set   shape "house"
                         set   size   0.6
                         set   color 15 ]
   calculate-exposure1 or calculate-exposure2    ;; choose one or the other
   end
```

```
to calculate-exposure1
   ask household 1 [ set healthy-exposure count healthy-shops in-radius 3
                     set pcolor 15
                     set unhealthy-exposure sum [unhealthy-shops] of neighbors ]
   end
```

```
to calculate-exposure2
   ask household 1 [ set healthy-exposure count healthy-shops with [ distance myself < 500]
                     set pcolor 15
                     set unhealthy-exposure sum [unhealthy-shops] of neighbors ]
   end
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a [mre]? Given the nature of your question, to create your reproducible example you might want to consider using `resize-world` and `random-seed` in your `setup`, so that we have the exact same geography of the world. What is necessary, however, is that you include the commands that you use to create your agents, and that you fix the errors that come from the second lines in both of your `calculate-exposure` procedures.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish with `sum [unhealthy-shops] of neighbors`? From what I see in the rest of your code, unhealthy-shops seems to be a breed of turtles rather than a patch-variable. Perhaps you are looking for something in the line of `sum [unhealthyness] of unhealthy-shops-on neighbors` ?